# How to give a Bar in a Stacked Bar Chart a minimal height using D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple stacked bar chart implemented with D3 and its [Stack Layout](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Stack-Layout.md).
Is there an easy way how I can ensure that each element inside of a stack has a minimal height? I want to ensure that an elements label has enough space to be displayed nicely.

I am aware that when I change the height of particular bar, the ratios to the other bars will not match exactly anymore. This is not a problem since the chart should only give a raw overview about the value distribution and does not have the requirement to be "that" exact.

[JSFiddle (B & C need minimal height)](https://jsfiddle.net/8fmu6ojL/)

```
-
```

Comment: By scaling the overall height of the diagram? The height of the individual stacks is a percentage of the height of the parent element, so make the parent element higher.

Comment: thank you for your reply @what. making the parent container taller is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Could you provide a demo or JSFiddle ?

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. If you cannot scale the whole graph, how do you expect to scale a part of it? The 2000 stack is one tenth the height of the 20000 stack and one fifth the height of the 10000 stack. If you scale the 2000 stack, then the others increase in height proportionally. If you cannot adapt the overall height, then part of the other stacks will push out of the containing element, becoming hidden, and your graph will look wrong. So either you scale it as a whole, including the container, or you don't scale it. Explain in more detail what you want to do.

Comment: If you can't change the height of the chart, have you considered alternative ways to display the labels?  Maybe something on hover or use a legend?

Fundamentally, if you can't change the height then there will never be enough space to display the label unless you alter the data (presumably not want you want!)

Comment: This can be done. Could you share a JSfiddle of your problem?

Comment: thanks for your inputs so far! just added a jsfiddle with a stripped down example of my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by postprocessing my data (warning, typescript ahead):

```
export function ensureMinHeight(heights: number[], minHeight: number): number[] {
    const c = correctionFactor(heights, minHeight);
    const fixedCorrectionFactor = correctionFactor(heights, minHeight, c);

    return heights.map((height) => {
        if (height < minHeight || height - fixedCorrectionFactor < minHeight) {
            return minHeight;
        }
        return height - fixedCorrectionFactor;
    });
}

function correctionFactor(heights: number[], minHeight: number, prevCorrectionFactor: number = 0) {
    const {totalAmountOfAdjustments, numberOfAdjustments } = heights.reduce((prev, height) => {
        if (height < minHeight || height - prevCorrectionFactor < minHeight) {
            return {
                totalAmountOfAdjustments: prev.totalAmountOfAdjustments + (minHeight - height),
                numberOfAdjustments: prev.numberOfAdjustments + 1
            };
        }
        return prev;
    }, { totalAmountOfAdjustments: 0, numberOfAdjustments: 0 });

    return totalAmountOfAdjustments / (heights.length - numberOfAdjustments);
}
```

this function is then applied on the values calculated by D3:

```
const heights = ensureMinHeight(children.map((c) => chartHeight - yScale(c.value)), 15);
```

the final `heights` array is then used to draw the SVG manually.